# jQuery hide by clicking outside of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello,

I'm trying to make a JavaScript dynamic display of an image.

Here’s my code:

```
<div class="info_image_click" style="display: none;">
    <img src="slike/info_slika_click.jpg" />
</div><!--kraj info_image_click-->

<a href="javascript:void(null);">
    <div class="info_image" style="margin: 0px auto;">
        <img src="slike/info_slika.jpg"/>
    </div>
</a><!-- info slika -->

<script>
    $('.info_image').click(function () {
        $('.info_image_click').show();
    });
</script>
```

When someone clicks on "info_image" (that's the small picture) it opens the "info_image_click"
(that's the large picture).
I don't know how users can hide the "info_image_click" by clicking outside container in which he is.
Sorry about my english :)

Comment: which jQuery you are using to open the image? show the link of some more code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.info_image').click(function (e) {

    // Used to stop the event bubbling..
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('.info_image_click').show();
});

// Hide the "info_image_click" by clicking outside container
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.info_image_click').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much,i'm still a rookie in this section.

Comment: Another question :) The image is in body tag,but I can't center it so it could be always be on the center of monitor.This is my body line in css: body {
 background-image: url("slike/noisy_net.png");
 background-repeat: repeat;
}

Comment: Try this: `background-image: url(slike/noisy_net.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;` inside the body tag :)

Comment: That's my main background,but this picture that I want to center is in my 1st question,exactly <div class="info_image_click" style="display: none;">
    <img src="slike/info_slika_click.jpg" />
</div>    this one

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$(document).not('. info_image_click').click(function() {
    // Do your hiding stuff here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add body click:

```
<script>
 $('.info_image').click(function () {
            $('.info_image_click').show();
            $("body").click(function () {
                $("info_image_click').hide();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to change your `DOM`,then there is no need of `jQuery` also

```
<a href="your large image"><img src="your small image"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is to get your image to be modal (i.e. the page below is inactive until the image is hidden), you can create an invisible overlay (with a very small opacity, typically 0.01) that is the same size of your page, and covers it, and has a z-index (a "vertical" position) between that of your page (which would typically be 0), and that of your "modal" zone (i.e. in this case the info_image_click image), which can be anything larger than 0.

Then you set the overlay click event so the image and the overlay get hidden when the overlay gets clicked.

By doing this, you ensure that when a user clicks on the window, if its inside the image, nothing happens (since the image has a higher z-index it will get the click event, which is not assigned), and if its outside the image, the overlay (and not the page, since it has a lower z-index) will get the click event and do what you want (hide the image and the overlay, thus returning to the main page).

You can put the overlay to a higher opacity than 0.01 if you want it to be a clue to the user that the image is modal.

Quick draft of how I would do it in jQuery:

```
showWindowModal: function(windowSelector) {
    $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("overlay")
        .appendTo($("#main"))
        .css({
            width: $("#main").outerWidth(),
            height: $("#main").outerheight()
        })
        .click(function() {
            $(windowSelector).remove();
            $("#main > div.overlay").remove();
        });
    $(windowSelector).addClass("modal").show();
}
```

css classes:

```
#main > div.overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.modal
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```