# hide div on background click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a series of divs that reveal on link click. When revealed i'm trying to make them close on background click while maintaining their ability to have the different divs replace each other when different links are clicked.

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/t593pyg9/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('a.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this).next('.toggle')
        $('.toggle').not(elem).hide();
        elem.toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: [jQuery hide by clicking outside of div][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164799/jquery-hide-by-clicking-outside-of-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to clicks on the entire document, to prevent this from closing the "popup" after clicking it's link due to event propagation add a `return false;` to the show click listener.

```
$('.toggle').hide();
$('a.togglelink').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).next('.toggle')
    $('.toggle').not(elem).hide();
    elem.toggle();
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    $('.toggle').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/ee91fvtz/)

---

## Update

If you want to prevent the popup from hiding on clicking on it add this:

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/ee91fvtz/1/)

Comment: This is nearly it but it has the side effect of preventing clicks working on links in the toggled div. I believe it needs to be an event.stopPropagation(); as opposed to e.preventDefault(); but im not totally clear on exactly how this would be implemented, or if im indeed correct... Any thoughts? My new JS attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/ee91fvtz/2/

Comment: You're right with `stopPropagation()`, this will prevent only your handlers while `preventDefault()` will prevent the browsers default handlers. Jquery's `return false` does both, so you should use `stopPropagation` instead of `return false` in the listener on `.toogle`, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee91fvtz/4/)